# oracle sysdate insert with text

Tags: oracle

I have to insert into a comment column in oracle with text that says

> current year rate is set on `sysdate`

where current year needs to be inserted as 2012 and sysdate giving todays date.

I know how to get the current year from `sysdate` but I'm stuck in inserting the above text into my column. Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update the_table
   set the_comment = 'current year rate is set on '||to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd');
```